# How to read more than one csv files from the command line in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I append all the files from command line to a list and then I have

```
filenames =['file1.csv', 'try.csv', 'new.csv']
```

I now want to access **file1.csv** first check some conditions, if they don't satisfy, then check the next file until then do.
Any help?

Comment: what should they satisfy ? what conditions are you looking for ?

Comment: Look at the csv module. Probably a slightly obvious comment but you don't seem to have tried anything so far.

Comment: it's supposed to read a row in the csv and check with the user input, if they match then the condition is satisfied and  no need to read the next file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a simple `for-loop` and a `with` `statement`:

```
import csv

filenames =['file1.csv', 'try.csv', 'new.csv']
for file in fienames:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
         for row in csv.reader(f):
             #do something (check user input whatever...)
```